# Continuous Random Variables $\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = f(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Given a continuous random variable $X$ with CDF $F(x)$ and PDF $f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x)$

Is there ever times where we differentiate a second time, or more?

That is to say, does $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}F(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ have any use in probability/statistics? Does it give us any information?

Thanks

Comment: i have never seen any place in probability theory where the derivative of the pdf is used.

Comment: Well sure, why not. The use is the same as in calculus, i.e. study maxima, convexity properties, etc of the density.